# How to Color Specific Data Points on a Plot Based on Column Value in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Let's say I have the following dataset:

```
d = {'Team': ['Duke', 'LSU'], 'Wins': [20, 18], 'Losses' : [5, 7], 'Conference' : ['ACC', 'SEC']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    Team    Wins   Losses   Conference
0   Duke     20      5          ACC
1   LSU      18      7          SEC
```

Then I make a scatterplot of it

```
plt.plot(d['Losses'], d['Wins'], 'o')
```

I would like to color code my scatter plot by Conference. More specifically, I would like to only color SEC teams red, while all other data points are the default blue. Additionally, how would I go about coloring *just* Duke red, while every other datapoint is blue? I have about 200 teams in my dataset. How would I ago about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you can try

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'Team': ['Duke', 'LSU'], 
     'Wins': [20, 18], 
     'Losses' : [5, 7], 
     'Conference' : ['ACC', 'SEC']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df["color"] = np.where(df["Conference"]=="SEC", "red", "blue")

df.plot(x='Losses', y='Wins', kind="scatter", color=df["color"]);
```

If then you want to use the same logic for Duke you just need to change the line with `np.where` accordingly.

**Update**
For this particular case I think you should have a look at `plotly`

```py
import plotly.express as px
px.scatter(df,x="Losses", y="Wins", color="Conference", hover_name="Team")
```

[image]

Comment: When I use the np.where, it just assigns blue for every row. Also, I wouldn't want to color code it by conference, I would just like to have one conference be a different color than all other data points (so essentially around 10 specific points would be red while 100 others are a different color).

Comment: If you have a conference called "SEC" `np.where` should assign red to it. Please check if you have whitespaces. I'm not sure to understand what do you mean. Do you want "SEC" to be red and a different color for each conference?

Comment: I want "SEC" to be red and all others be blue.

Comment: When you reproduce all my code including the definition of `df` do you have `SEC` in red and the other in blue?

Comment: Okay I got the np.where to work, but I get "ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 0       red" when I try the plot. I'm doing a sns reg plot and put color = df['color']

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I got it, the correct syntax is scatter_kws={'facecolors':df['color']}. Your np.where helped tremendously. Thank you so much.